# Checking an <a> elements text value against a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really need your help with coding this for me. How can I check an `<a>`'s text element against a string value to see if the tab already exists or not?

I apologize in advance as I am new to this and I am not sure how to accomplish this. An answer using jQuery is fine as well.

```
var x = "tabTwo"

Some new function here to check and see if the string value tabTwo matches any of the existing tab text values, return true or false.
```

Here is the HTML markup/structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that understood your problem, but I'll provide you 2 solutions.

1) If you want to check using the id

```js
function isTabExistsById(id) {
  return $('.tabs a[href="#'+id+'"]').length > 0;
}

console.log(isTabExistsById('tab1')); // true
console.log(isTabExistsById('tab3')); // true
console.log(isTabExistsById('tabFour')); // false
console.log(isTabExistsById('tab5')); // false
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2) If you want to check using the content

```js
function isTabExistsByCaption(text) {
  var result = false;
  
  $('.tabs a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == text) {
      result = true;
      return;
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(isTabExistsByCaption('tabOne')); // true
console.log(isTabExistsByCaption('tabFour')); // true
console.log(isTabExistsByCaption('tabFive')); // false
console.log(isTabExistsByCaption('tab3')); // false
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope, I understood your problem. If no, could you explain it with more details, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can target the a element with jQuery by giving it a class or id and targeting it like so.

```
$('#tab1');
```

And then you can get the value using `.text()` (or many other options)

```
$('#tab1').text();
```

And then you can compare it.

```
if ($('#tab1').text() === x) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

You can further abstract this by assigning all the a tags a shared class and looping through them, and targeting using `$(this)`.

```
$('.tab_link').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() === x) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the `a` tag and then you can try :

```
var link = $('.link').text();
if(link == "some Value")
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give a unique class attribute for you 'a' tags. and select the 'a' using jquery like this

```
$('.classname').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() == 'tabTwo' { //here you have it

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = "tabTwo"
var tabArray = document.querySelectorAll('li>a');

tabArray.forEach((elem)=>{
if(match === elem.innerText){
  return true;
}
return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to get all `<a>` elements using `$("a")` and iterate through them via `.each(function() {...}`. Inside the loop, you have to check, does the `text()` of current element equal to needed string: if it is - then we change `tabExists` variable from `false` to `true`. In my example I have written separate function, so you can invoke it with any parameter you like. I have called `checkTabExistence("tabTwo")` which should log `true` and `checkTabExistence("tabSix")` which should log `false`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  checkTabExistence("tabTwo");
  checkTabExistence("tabSix");
});

function checkTabExistence(stringToCheck) {
  var tabExists = false;
  $("a").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() === stringToCheck) {
      tabExists = true;
    }
  });
  console.log(stringToCheck + " exists: " + tabExists);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
</ul>
```